# Redirect and hide part of url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I need an url like this one:

```
d-asdas.local/sometext
```

That if has some text after `local/` should redirect to

```
d-asdas.local/homepage.php/sometext
```

And the last thing, the url above should hide the `homepage.php`, so what will be visible in the url bar is this mask.

```
d-asdas.local/sometext
```

This can be done in `.htaccess`?

Comment: Certainly it is. You can use the features of mod_redirect inside .htaccess files, if the servers configuration permits. I suggest you read the manual. It is very well written offers lots of examples and is the first hit in Google.

Comment: Just a sub-note on what arkascha correctly said before me.

The second one (masking the URL) can be done using mod_rewrite inside .htaccess files if the server permits :)